# Show that the limits of the following does not exist

Tags: limits, analysis

Show that the limit of the following does not exist $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

I solve it in paper using polar polar coordinates $x= r\cos\theta$, $x= r\sin\theta$, and then i cancel out the $r^2$ and I am left with $$\lim\limits_{r \to 0} (\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta)$$

i also put ${(x,y)\to(0,0)}$ and i get $\frac{0}{0}$ form directly

Is the following the true way to solve the answer

Comment: You can consider two paths as $(x,y)\to (0,1)$: one is $y=0, x\to 0$, and the other is $x=0,y\to 0$, then you will get different limits!

Comment: @Riemann so the way i solve is totally wrong ?

Comment: Its ok (Up to a misprint:  it should say $\cos^2 \theta  -  \sin^2 \theta$). You just have to realize that your calculation leads to infinitely many results (one for each value of $\theta$), so....

Comment: @Hamza Your method is OK.  Different $\theta$ gives different limit! For example, $\theta=0$ gives limit $1$ and $\theta=\pi/2$ gives limit $-1$.

Comment: Hint: Put $y=mx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(x,y)=(t,t)$, where $t\rightarrow0^+$ we get  $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=0\rightarrow0,$

but for $(x,y)=(t,t^2),$ where $t\rightarrow0^+$ we see that $$\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{t^2-t^4}{t^2+t^4}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\rightarrow1.$$

Comment: Please search for duplicates of obvious standard homework problems instead of answering them.

Answer (score 1):

Put $y=mx$ we get $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}$$ so it’s dependts on $m$ i.e. doesn’t exist.

In yours case it’s depends on $\theta$ so doesn’t exist.